# use jquery hover from class method

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events, hover

I'm trying to use `.hover` method of `jquery` in a javascript class:

```
var test = {

    init:function(){
        $("#elm li").hover(test.showTitle(this), test.hideTitle());
    },
    showTitle:function(e){
        ...
    },
    hideTitle: function(){
        ...
    }

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    test.init();
});
```

but here `this` refers to class itself and not to `eventObject`.
How can I listen for events with jquery from a javascript class?

Comment: did you try bind instead of direct hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply remove the parenthesis and the usage of the `this` keyword, jQuery will call your functions with the required variables as expected within the context of the element.

```
var test = {

    init:function(){
        $("#elm li").hover(test.showTitle, test.hideTitle);
    },
    showTitle:function(e){
        console.log(e)
        console.log(this);
    },
    hideTitle: function(){
    }

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    test.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be applying that to each element that is returned by your class query.

```
$("#elm li").each(function() {
    var $self = $(this);

    $self.hover(test.showTitle($self), test.hideTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the call in an anonymous function that gives you access to `e`.

```
#("elm li").hover(function(e) {
    test.showTitle(e); //or this
}, function(e) {
   test.hideTitle(e); //or this
});
```